# RadioButton unaligned with UI in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Below image you see the red circle indicators where it's only possible to click and radiobutton works, but I want to scoop them to the correct place(to the left so it's aligned with UI), which I don't know how. I tried TranslationY=-80 but it didn't work.

[image: Example of my radiobutton UI in MAUI]

**Styles.xaml:**

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
    <Frame BorderColor="#F3F2F1" CornerRadius="2" BackgroundColor="#F3F2F1" HasShadow="False" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#FF3300" />
                            <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                            <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid Margin="4" WidthRequest="80">
            <Grid WidthRequest="18" HeightRequest="18" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Ellipse Stroke="Blue" Fill="White" WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="check" Fill="Blue" WidthRequest="8" HeightRequest="8" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

**MyPage.xaml:**

```xml
<StackLayout Spacing="3">
    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedTheme, StringFormat='Theme: {0}'}" FontSize="20" />
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="themes" RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTheme, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <RadioButton Value="{x:Static am:AppTheme.Unspecified}" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image Scale="0.75" Source="{FontImage FontFamily=FAS, Glyph={x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Gear}, Color=#323130}"  />
                    <Label FontSize="Small" Text="System" TextColor="#323130" />
                </StackLayout>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Value="{x:Static am:AppTheme.Light}" Grid.Column="1" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image Scale="0.75" Source="{FontImage FontFamily=FAS, Glyph={x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Sun}, Color=#323130}" />
                    <Label FontSize="Small" Text="Light" TextColor="#323130" />
                </StackLayout>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Value="{x:Static am:AppTheme.Dark}" Grid.Column="2" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image Scale="0.75" Source="{FontImage FontFamily=FAS, Glyph={x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Moon}, Color=#323130}" />
                    <Label FontSize="Small" Text="Dark" TextColor="#323130" />
                </StackLayout>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say it is a potential issue or by design .

To solve the problem/as a workaround , you can add a `TapGestureRecognizer` on `ContentPresenter` to enable the RadioButton manually .

##### Sample code

```
//xaml
<ContentPresenter >
    <ContentPresenter.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </ContentPresenter.GestureRecognizers>
</ContentPresenter>


//code behind
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ContentPresenter cp = sender as ContentPresenter;
   var button = cp.Content.Parent as RadioButton;
   button.IsChecked = true;
}
```